# SQL constraint for limiting a daily task

Tags: sql, date, constraints

I am teaching myself SQL and I am stuck.  I have a Car-garage database with a table called Tasks.  The table Tasks has 3 columns: Tasknumber(PK), NumberPlate, and DaySchedule.  In the DDL I want to use a constraint which checks the number of plates and allows only one task a day.

The below is what I have tried.  However, it restricts per record instead of per number of plates.

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks (
   Tasknumber    NUMERIC(5)   not null,
   NumberPlate   VARCHAR(8)   not null,
   DaySchedule   DATE         not null,
   Description   VARCHAR(255) null,
   CONSTRAINT PK_Tasknumber PRIMARY KEY  (Tasknumber),
     D AS DAY(DaySchedule) PERSISTED,
     M AS MONTH(DaySchedule) PERSISTED,
     Y AS YEAR(DaySchedule) PERSISTED,
  CONSTRAINT UQ_DATA_DMY UNIQUE(D,M,Y)
)
```

What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only need a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(NumberPlate, DaySchedule)`. Then, for every `NumberPlate`, there will be at most one Task per Day.